# HAProxy http response rewrite rspirep string

Tags: haproxy

Scenario is HAProxy as a reverse-proxy for a Docker user-defined network, so the servers are reachable by service name from HAProxy. Inbound works, but I can't seem to get the response rewrite to work.

I need any traffic, foo.com/api/* to be redirected to api:9999/*.

Current config

```
frontend https
    acl api path_beg /api
    use_backend api if api

backend api
    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)api[/]?(.*)     \1\2
    rspirep (.*) /api/
    server api api:9999 check
```

I'm pretty sure this is what's needed, but I suspect my rspirep string is NOT correct. Any help is appreciated!